# How to enable cookies in WPF WebBrowser Control

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I need to enable cookies in my WPF application WebBrowser control even if it is disabled in the IE settings.
After going through many questions this is what i tried, but this does not work.

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, ref int flag, int dwBufferLength);

    static bool EnableCookies(int settingCode, int option)
    {
        if (!InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, settingCode, ref option, sizeof(int)))
        {
            var ex = Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
            //throw ex;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        EnableCookies(81, 1);
    }
```

If this is not possible, I wish to at least be able to get the setting value to show the user an error message that cookies are not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

webbrowser control uses **wininet** for networking, specifically use the internetSetCookie(Ex) and **internetGetCookie(Ex)** functions for Cookie management. There isn't a **wininet** wrapper in **.Net**, but you can p-invoke.

The WPF webbrowser does not expose all the features of the winforms webbrowser.  The way to get around this is to host the winforms webbrowser in a WindowsFormsHost.

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
xmlns:wb="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
Title="WpfWebBrowser" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <my:WindowsFormsHost>
        <wb:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser"></wb:WebBrowser>
    </my:WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

see description here [get-cookie-string-from-wpfs-webbrowser](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1edb6537-0566-4c18-912e-1dc86930df9c/how-can-i-get-cookie-string-from-wpfs-webbrowser?forum=wpf)

Comment: As you can see in the posted code that I am using wininet functions to enable cookie settings, but it does not work.