# WPF Webbrowser acting strange

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF application using WPF WebBrowser control. The appilcation is running on windows (as a Kiosk). The webbrowser is configured to ***show some service from the web***. When the users try to **sign in**, **that website redirect to the 3rd party Authentication Provider (SAML)**. After the user had successfully sign-ined, the 3rd party Authentication Provider **redirect the user to the original website**. 
And the **original website shows the error that the website needs the *"cookies to be enable"*.** 

When using the **Windows Forms Browser inside the WindowsFormHost on the same WPF application, there's no such error.**

On IE11 there's also no error.

The **website and 3rd party Authentication provider is not under my control**.

The WPF WebBrowser control in the application is forced to use **IE11 through BrowserEmulation.**

Can someone tell me why the **WPF WebBrowser control behavior is different from the WindowsForm Browser control?**

Comment: I believe your best option is to [host the WinForms browser in a WindowsFormsHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959810/how-to-enable-cookies-in-wpf-webbrowser-control)

Comment: @MarkFeldman, yes. Thanks for your suggestion. But I'm baffled by the wpf webbrowser's control's behavior. On winforms browser control, there's no problem. And I understand that the two controls use the same underlying control.

Comment: I've had all manner of nightmares with the WPF WebBrowser control, they seem to have disabled a lot of functionality. They're also using an older version of the browser (IE8 I believe) which doesn't support all the backward compatibility stuff.

Comment: If you are looking for a decent web broswer control for WPF checkout: http://cefsharp.github.io

Comment: @d347hm4n, yes I use CEFSharp for other projects. But for this one I needed to use WPF webbrowser control. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @MarkFeldman, I didn't know about that (IE8 being used underlying WPF WebBrowser Control).

Comment: Have you tried this code? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303

Comment: @Noseratio, I haven't tried that yet. I will try. Thanks.

Comment: @Noseratio I tried already, but it's not working.